# Hibernate Criteria: relation “my_table” does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity:

```
@Table(schema="my_schema",name="my_table")
public class MyTable
...
```

And i want to retrieve records from that table:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(entityClass);
List list = criteria.list();
```

I get:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: relation “my_table” does not exist
```

I suspect that it's because of the missing schema name in front of `my_table` but how to add it, or maybe there's another reason?

Comment: Does mytable exist? What is your connection string? Does it include schema?

Comment: You need to define schema like <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME</prop>

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, it exists. I make connection to DB through JNDI lookup. And no it doesn't include schema name because DB designed so, that there are many schemas

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha I'm using application.properties file and i've added `hibernate.default_schema=MY_SCHEMA` but result is same

Comment: include schema name in connection string - unless you are using multiple schemas?

Comment: @Antoniossss That's the thing. I'm using multiple schemas.

Comment: Since you included schema name, it should work. Turn on hibernate's query log to see what kind of sql is generated. Maybe somewhere you got a timple typo or restricted character and escaping is required.

Comment: @ Antoniossss Ok i added schema name so my connection-url looks like this: `jdbc:postgresql://10.60.6.34:5432/postgres/my_schema`. But now i have this error: `FATAL:database postgres/my_schema` doesn't exists. By the way `postgres` is the name of my database.

Answer (score 0):

Is your schema name begin with uppercase?
i have a similar case, my table name is `users` and schema is `D2018`.

i've got error like this :

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "d2018.users" does not exist

it seems hibernate try to connect to `d2018` schema not `D2018`, so i rename my schema to `d2018` and now it's work flawless